Show histograms of individual layers in TensorBoard with Keras "model.fit"
I have a Keras sequential model with two hidden layers. I would like to see in TensorBoard a histogram of the kernel and bias of each layer individually. I.e. a Histogram for Layer_1/Bias, Layer_1/Kernel, Layer_2/Bias and Layer_2/Kernel. Like for example here:
Image showing kernel and bias of Layer_1 and Layer_2 in individual histograms
But in my case I get only one histogram for "Kernel" and one for "Bias" in TensorBoard, and it seems this is for both layers combined, as shown below:
Image showing only one combined Histogram for "Bias" and one for "Kernel"
My model definition is as follows:
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input(shape=(1,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', name='layer_1'))
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', name='layer_2'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
...
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
...
model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs = 50, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

using:
TensorBoard 2.18.0
Keras 3.7.0
Python 3.11
I am quite new to TensorBoard and got stuck at this point for quite a while now.
I saw solutions for the case when a custom training loop (tf.GradientTape) is implemented, but I wonder if there is a solution when using the high level Keras model.fit function.
